# How do I make a KeyListener react only when getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT?

Tags: java, key-bindings, keyevent

I am trying to make a game where playerOne uses the **left** shift key in order to make his move (complete his turn), and playerTwo uses the **right** shift key. However, when making a small program for testing, I've created a KeyEvent object and used getKeyLocation() along with an if statement, but sadly, to no avail.